# global sections of the pullback bundle under finite map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f :X \to Y$ be a finite morphism of degree $d$ between two algebraic curves (over the field of complex numbers). Assume that we have a $g^r_n$ on the curve $Y$ (a line bundle $L$ on $Y$ having degree $n$ and sections exactly $r+1$), then we know that $f^*(L)$ is a line bundle bundle on $X$ having degree $dn$. What can be said about global section of $f^*(L)$?

Do we have $h^0(f^*(L)) \geq h^0(L)$?

If this is the case then can we take a sublinear system of the pullback bundle and say that $g^r_n$ on $Y$ gives us $g^r_{dn}$ on $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the characteristic of the base field is coprime to the degree of $f$ then yes. Indeed,
$$
H^0(X, f^*L) \cong 
H^0(Y, f_*f^*L) \cong 
H^0(Y, L \otimes f_*\mathcal{O}_X).
$$
and $\mathcal{O}_Y$ is a direct summand of $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: I'm working over the field of complex numbers (the number $0$ is coprime to only $1,-1$) what happens when $d=2,3$ say? and if $h^0(f^*(L)) \geq h^0(L)$, then does my last conclusion about sublinear system make sense?

Comment: Characteristic zero is (by convension) coprime to any $d$, so you are fine. And yes, if $g^r_n$ gives a map $\phi \colon Y \to \mathbb{P}^{r-1}$ then the map $\phi \circ f \colon X \to \mathbb{P}^{r-1}$ is given by a subsystem of its pullback.